# Dynamic Linear Model (DLM) vs Weighted Linear Regression

Tags: regression, time-series, linear-model, weighted-regression, dlm

In Applied Bayesian Forecasting and Time Series Analysis (1994, page 14), they state:

The passage of time erodes the value of information - sales figures from six months ago are potentially less useful than figures for last month when predicting sales for this month.

In short: They are saying that a dynamic model puts more emphasis on local observations when forecasting ahead. However, a simple linear regression model would put the same emphasis (weighting) on sales from six months ago and on sales from last month. This may be problematic when forecasting since we may want to weight more recent observations more heavily than observations from a long time ago.

I understand how a DLM does this, but my question is: Can a DLM be represented as a weighted linear regression? Or, at least, can a weighted linear regression perform just as good as a DLM (if not precisely the same)?

I could define a suitable weight function, $\omega$, that could put more weighting on sales from last month than sales from six months ago.

The reason I said "not precisely the same" above is because it may be difficult to chose a weight function that weights the observations the same way as the DLM equations, but in theory, should the two models do the same thing?

What are the pros of using a DLM over a weighted linear regression?

Comment: Hi: you might be able to find weights for one point in time. but, as time passes and new data arrives and other data gets older,  that's probably not going to be possible, or atleast not easy.  Note that exponential smoothing can sort of do what you're describing but that can be viewed as a pseudo-bayesian approach or atleast definitely not a regression approach.